# How to get rid of stammering while speaking

Tags: spoken-english

Obviously, All of you while learning it, have experienced stammering despite the fact you know English well. The same story goes here, I've been doing my best to become fluent, I know how to speak and what to, though, the thing is I still have no idea why I stammer while speaking. I've memorized songs but still no much difference.

Some say recording your own voice it'll help with both accent and hesitation, I haven't tried though. I'm looking for some solution from some guys who have been through the same and how they've dealt with that.

Some experts say, fluency comes along with repetition that's why they've built some methods based this idea called deep learning. But repeating the same stuff for a while, asking me? Uh boring out of mind. So there have to be some other ways some guys have noticed/figured out.

Me? I started to figure out while I imagine what I'm talking about it helps me a lot but still doesn't do that much good. Despite being an EFL student still I know some guys who don't stammer while speaking just after 4 years of learning.

I'm looking for a set of solutions, everyone in the same page has come across.

Comment: Hi Devin, ELL is not really the right place for this question. You would be better off looking at http://www.stammering.org for solutions.

Comment: Do you have anyone around to speak English with? If so use every opportunity for practicing it. The good thing is, as you said, you have a good knowledge of English. So the onlything is that you need practice more. You should use it a lot to help your mind get used to using English whenever you demand it. Speaking to yourself is a good idea too, you don't need to necessarily be infront of a mirro.

Comment: You know, I belive in God, and I sometimes use English to talk to Him! The wonderful thing is He knows all langueges:-). So you can try it too. Memorizing some sentences for special situatins to readily use them. One of my profs once said:"you should speak in English, think in English, and dream in English. If you use English a lot, you will dream in English. I have experienced it:D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about learning the English language.

Answer (score 1):

Though this isn't a problem just with English, this is a site for learning a language and I think this question belongs for that reason.  I know for me (currently learning Spanish, German, and French) the most helpful thing is always to practice speaking about something I really care about - politics, science, et cetera - with a native or fluent speaker if possible. Example sentences from books get boring very quickly, and it's easy to fall in the trap of memorizing translations rather than actually learning the language.

Also, it's important that as much as possible you don't try to translate from your first language into English as you're talking.  Challenge yourself to work around words you don't know rather than just asking for a translation.  Make sure people you're practicing with don't just give you the answers, it's okay to have to think for a bit to find the right word.

Finally, be confident. I'm fairly fluent in Spanish but if I start to get nervous about making mistakes I start stammering and panicking.  Relax, and trust that you're going to be understood even if a conjugation sounds messed up or a clause gets put in a weird place.